# Fechar um popup aberto com window.open() com javascript

Tags: php, javascript, popup

Tenho um código JS para abrir um popup com window.open() e preciso fechá-lo depois de 1 segundo. Quando mando a url "https://api.whatsapp.com/" ele faz o que preciso, mas se enviar o link com parâmetros: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5596991100451" a tela não fecha.

Código HTML:

```
    <div 
    class="whats-link" 
    data-href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55<?=$cliente['telefone1'];?>"
    onclick="openNewWindow(this);" 
    style="cursor:pointer;">
      Whatsapp 1
      <i class="icon-wts fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
```

Código JS:

```
    function openNewWindow(el) {
        let url = el.getAttribute('data-href')
        let openedWindow = window.open(url, 'newwindow', 'height=200,width=200')
        setTimeout(() => {
            openedWindow.close()
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Já tentou substituir o let openedWindow por var openedWindow?

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Envie a sua variável para a arrow function criada

```
function openNewWindow(el) {
   let url = el.getAttribute('data-href')
   let openedWindow = window.open(url, 'newwindow', 'height=200,width=200')
   setTimeout((openedWindow) => {
      openedWindow.close()
   }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Eu já tinha tentando assim. Obrigado de qualquer forma.